# When to make stripe subscription object and assign to user - Django

Tags: django, stripe-payments

Tech Stack - Django, Angular
I have been implementing stripe subscription model but stuck at some absurd scenario. I am getting Subscription not found by django. Please read the full scenario.

Firstly I am successfull in creating stripe session.
Code

```
session = stripe.checkout.Session.create(
                            metadata={'price_id':request.data.get('price_id'),'product_id':request.data.get('product_id'),'product_name':request.data.get('product_name')},
                            client_reference_id=request.user.id,
                            customer=customer.stripe_customer_id,
                            success_url='http://localhost:4200/success?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}',
                            cancel_url='http://localhost:4200/canceled.html',
                            mode='subscription',
                            line_items=[{
                                'price': request.data['price_id'],
                                # For metered billing, do not pass quantity
                                'quantity': 1,
                            }],
                            )
```

Webhooks Implementation:

1. checkout.session.completed
   I am creating customer and subscription model in my db.

```
                print(user)
                customer = RecruiterUserProfile.objects.get(user = user)
                print(customer)
                customer.customer_id = session.customer
                customer.save()
                stripecustomer = Customer.objects.get(recruiter = customer, checkout_session_id = stripe_session_id)
                print(stripecustomer)
                stripecustomer.stripe_customer_id = stripe_customer_id
                stripecustomer.save()
                subscription,created = Subscriptions.objects.get_or_create(recruiter = customer,    
                                                sub_id=stripe_subscription_id,customer_id = stripecustomer,stripe_customer_id = stripe_customer_id,
                                                payment_status=stripe_payment_status, amount = stripe_amount,
                                                    status = stripe_status, product_id = stripe_metadata['product_id'], price_id = stripe_metadata['price_id'], product_name = stripe_metadata['product_name'])
```

2. invoice.paid
   Then it triggers Invoice.paid, in which I am getting the subscription model and update others values in it. But since webhooks do not wait for our calls, Sometimes, It doesn't find the subscription.

Now if I create subscription and customer in invoice.paid webhook using ger_or_create, How am I supposed to link it to the user.

Below are my models:

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    recruiter = models.OneToOneField(RecruiterUserProfile, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    stripe_customer_id = models.CharField(max_length=80, blank=True, null=True)
    checkout_session_id = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True,null=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.recruiter.user.email} has a stripe customer id {self.stripe_customer_id}"


def expiration():
    return now() + timedelta(days=30)
class Subscriptions(models.Model):
    STATUS_CHOICES =(
        ('utilised','Utilised'),
        ('accessible','Accessible'),
        ('notaccessible','Notaccessible')
        )
    recruiter = models.ForeignKey(RecruiterUserProfile, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    customer_id = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    stripe_customer_id = models.CharField(max_length=80, blank=True, null=True)
    sub_id = models.CharField(max_length=80, blank=True, null=True)
    product_id = models.CharField(max_length=80, blank=True, null=True)
    product_name = models.CharField(max_length=80, null=True, blank=True)
    price_id = models.CharField(max_length=80, blank=True, null=True)
    offer_id = models.CharField(max_length=80, blank=True, null=True)
    notes = models.JSONField(default=list,blank=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="Initial")
    payment_status = models.CharField(max_length = 100, default='')
    amount = models.CharField(max_length=20,blank=True, null=True)
    start_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    expiration_date = models.DateTimeField(
        default=expiration,
        verbose_name='Expirate in'
    )
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    client_validity = models.CharField(max_length=20,choices= STATUS_CHOICES, default='accessible')
    product_job_credits = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    active_job_credits = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    is_cancelled = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Comment: If a subscription ID is created successfully, it's not possible for Stripe not to find subscription details. Could you share the code how you retrieve the Subscription information? When the subscription retrieval is successful, you'd should be able to find customer ID from the response.

Comment: Yes, I am able to find all the details but it's an workflow issue. Like when I need to create an object in my local db 2 webhooks hit simultanoesly and does wait for the previous object creation hence when second webhook hits, it gives us object not found.

Comment: I see! It sounds like you're referring to the object in your database and not from Stripe. One way I can think of is that you only listens to `checkout.session.completed` event for initial subscription creation and ignore the `invoice.paid` event if subscription ID is not found in your database. In the future billing cycle, subscription ID will definitely be found. Alternatively, you can save `invoice.paid` event in your own database first, then process it later.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this question by just simple workflow change. Do not call the subscription API directly. Create a stripe customer initially by yourself and store the value in your local db. So while creation subscription, you will be able to get the customer and It will be easy to link the subscription with the customer.

I can share the code if necessary.